# Different result/output for same wsdl in Postman, SOAP UI, jdeveloper Http Analyzer

Tags: java, postman, soapui, jdeveloper

I have a wsdl url which is giving different result when I am testing with Postman, SOAP UI, Jdeveloper Http Analyzer even tough passing same request header and body in all tools.

In Postman, Jdeveloper Http Analyzer it's wsdl returning same 500-Internal server error.
In SOAP UI, it's returning correct result.

I have created Custom Java client application in jdeveloper to consume webservice, in that I am getting below error

The Error

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.UnsupportedMediaException: Unsupported Content-Type: application/xml Supported ones are: [text/xml]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:220)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:151)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.decode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:299)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.createResponsePacket(HttpTransportPipe.java:268)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:217)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:130)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:95)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1121)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1035)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1004)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:862)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:448)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:178)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:77)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:147)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.getService(Unknown Source)
    at someClient.SomeClient.main(WaselClient.java:23)
```

How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

When I am importing wsdl into SOAPUI request payload is loading without spaces in the header parameter.

for eg., content-type=”text/xml;charset=utf-8”(check there is no gap between xml; and charset),

where as in postman and jdeveloper http analyzer request payload is loading with spaces in the header parameter. content-type=”text/xml; charset=utf-8”(check there is a gap between xml; and charset).

Due to this it was giving different result.